# In Firebase, how do I grab the first children of a snapshot?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I always iterate the children.

`snapshot.forEach((item) => { } ));`

However, I'd like to just grab the first one.

Comment: Right now there simply isn't enough information in your question to answer with any degree of certainty. We need to know how your `snapshot` came to be, and likely to see the JSON you're reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping over the children is the correct way to do it.

> Even when there is only a single match for the query, the snapshot is still a list; it just contains a single item. To access the item, you need to loop over the result

This applies when using limitToFirst(1) and limitToLast(1) as well.

You can read more about it [here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data)